# Android - First run of Restlet 2.2 server - No available server connector

Tags: java, android, restlet, restlet-2.0

I´m trying to run my first Restlet server with this code:

```
import org.restlet.Server;
import org.restlet.data.Protocol;
import org.restlet.resource.Get;
import org.restlet.resource.ServerResource;

public class WebServer extends ServerResource {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public WebServer() throws Exception {
        // Create the HTTP server and listen on port 8182
        Server server = new Server(Protocol.HTTP, 8182, WebServer.class);
        server.start();

    }

    @Get
    public String present() {
        return "hello, world";
    }
}
```

But when I start the server, I get this error message:

`No available server connector supports the required protocols: 'HTTP' . Please add the JAR of a matching connector to your classpath. Then, register this connector helper manually.`

I copied the "org.restlet.jar" to the \libs folder and add JAR to the Libraries in Java Build Path. What should I do? What is wrong?

Comment: you do not need to do this anymore "add JAR to the Libraries in Java Build Path"

Comment: I remove it from the Libraries, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding it

Comment: Or do you have some instructions/tutorial how to import Restlet to the Android project in Eclipse?

Comment: I tried older version (2.1.7) and it´s OK. Is there any problem with the newest version?

Comment: I can confirm that 2.1.7 is ok. Directly swapping to 2.2.2 causes the issue. Problem is, 2.1.7 has memory leak issues. Anyone know if there's a stable version of this?

Answer (score 3):

it's possible to run it if you configure it to use the NIO HttpServerHelper. Simply downloading the NIO extension and configuring it in the RestLet Engine will allow you to spin up an HTTP server again. (Tested on 2.3.1).

```java
import org.restlet.ext.nio.HttpServerHelper; 

...

Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredServers().clear();
Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredServers().add(new HttpServerHelper(null));
```

To see if the NIO extension is available for your edition you can have a look on:
http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.3/extensions/editions-matrix

Comment: This answer should be accepted. Using NIO extension and registering the HttpServerHelper did fix the problem for me.

Comment: The answer also helps with 2.3.6 where this problem still occurs.